# Publishing Web api asp net wep project in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7

пытаюсь разобраться как работать IIS и как хостить мои asp.net приложения. Задаю вопрос, так как не получается захостить. Я проделываю нужные шаги(как я думаю правильные), но в итоге получаю ошибку 404, в общем давайте я опишу как я делал, может я что-то не понял. Прошу поправьте меня, если я что то неверное сделал.

Установка IIS:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того, как я поставил галочки на нужных компонентах, а в Visual Studio создал простой проект Asp.Net WebApi. Построил апи с методами Post и Get, неважно что они делают. Получается если я запускаю через Visual Studio, то есть проект временно хоститься на IIS Express, то я спокойно вижу результаты запросов. Теперь же мне надо опубликовать.

Выбрал IIS, потом выбрал FileSystem и указал путь к некоторой папке, хорошо опубликовал. Дальше захожу в диспетчер служб IIS. Опробовал я тут 2 способа по разному:

Первый, это создать сайт, указав физический путь к той папке публикации проекта, порт 80, имя узла localhost. Значит в браузере я использовал следующий url localhost/api/Word. Получаю, ошибку 404, код ошибки 0x80070002.

Второй способ, это не создавать отдельный сайт, а добавить виртуальную папку к Default Web Site, указав путь к расположению самого проекта. Потом я преобразовал в приложение. Пытаюсь получить доступ используя url: localhost/MyFirstApi/api/Word. Опять же получаю 404 и код ошибки 0x80070002.

Все шаги взяты из гайдов, никакой самодеятельности. Может кто помочь разобраться?

Скрин самого результата url:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что это все связано с 8080 портом, но я даж не знаю, что с ним делать, ведь его заняла система PID 4. Посмотрел на ноуте, там система занимает другие порты, хм странно.

Comment: Не в порте дело. Были заняты порты 80 и 8080, 8080 я смог освободить, создал сайт где указал другой порт(тот который освободил 8080), в итоге тоже самое. Хз даж че делать

Comment: В данный момент 80й и 8080 занимает Служба вэб публикаций, без которой IIS не работает, ищу дальше в чем дело

Answer (score 0):

Проблема возникла из-за 2х причин:

1) Я использовал не тот пул приложений. Для ASP.NET и WEBapi в том числе нужен пул для .NET 4.0, а по умолчанию стоит .Net 2.0

После установки нужного пула проблема не пропала. Так как кроме пула приложений должны быть нужные фильтры ISAPI для APS.NET 4.0. Я не совсем понимаю, что это за фильтры, по этому оставлю объяснение на тех кто шарит.

2) В общем как добавил. через командную строку сменил директорию на C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319. После прописал команду установки ASP.NET v4.0: .\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

По окончанию установки сразу все заработало и появились нужные фильтры 4.0.
Гайд по исправлению: https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/HTTP-Error-4040---Not-Found-(MapRequestHandler--StaticFile)-when-deploying-WCF-Web-API-on-IIS-7x/